# Performance difference in accessing an item in an array vs pointer reference?

Tags: c, performance

I'm fresh to C - used to scripting languages like, PHP, JS, Ruby etc. Got a query in regard to performance. I know one should not micro optimize too early - however, I'm writing a Ruby C Extension for Google SketchUp where I'm doing lots of 3D calculations so performance is a concern. (And this question is also for learning how C works.)

Often many iterations is done to process all the 3D data so I'm trying to work out what might be faster.

I'm wondering if accessing an array entry many times is faster if I make a pointer reference to that array entry? What would common practice be?

```
struct FooBar arr[10];
int i;
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
  arr[i].foo = 10;
  arr[i].bar = 20;
  arr[i].biz = 30;
  arr[i].baz = 40;
}
```

Would this be faster or slower? Why?

```
struct FooBar arr[10], *item;
int i;
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
  item = &arr[i];
  item->foo = 10;
  item->bar = 20;
  item->biz = 30;
  item->baz = 40;
}
```

I looked around and found discussions about variables vs pointers - where it was generally said that pointers required extra steps since it had to look up the address, then the value - but in general there wasn't a bit hit.

But what I was wondering was if accessing an array entry in C has much of a performance hit? In Ruby it is faster to make a reference to the entry if you need to access it many time - but that's Ruby...

Comment: In theory there is no difference (as long your array fits into cache). Problem will appear once it does not fit into cache.

Comment: You can try both alternatives, and then look at the generated assembly code. My guess is that the compiler will optimize both to the same code anyway.

Comment: "I know one should not micro optimize too early", but you're going to do so anyway

Comment: @AoeAoe Why? My view is that good compilers will emit identical code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well, that could be dependeng on compilers asumption of how big array will be. If compiler knows it will not fit into cache it will create different code (depends on compiler and architecture). I had a nice picture from one lecture, but I can't find it so I'll try to describe what I have in mind:
Imagine struct FooBar that does exactly fit into cache (exmpl1) and you do some operations on it, then you change pointer and load new struct into cache (this is nice). In exmpl2 it would have to load different struct into cache every single time.

Comment: @AoeAoe I can't make sense of that.

Comment: '"I know one should not micro optimize too early", but you're going to do so anyway' - In Ruby there is such a big difference that when you run many iterations it's quickly significant so I use it all the time. Wondered if it was of any concern at all in C or if I would just ignore it.

Comment: @David: how can he avoid micro-optimizing early, without first getting some feel for what is (in C) a micro-optimization as opposed to an "obvious" major performance drag? Questioner doesn't state that he's going to micro-optimize anyway, he asks whether or not this is the kind of thing you can neglect.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The way cache works is that it preloads chunk of memory into smaller memory (cache) within processor. Processor before looking into ram, looks in different levels (cache L1, L2,L3) and if it does not find needed data, it goes for it into memory (aka cache miss). If you have array [million][million] and you do some operations on it, you will get big performance boost if you acces it sequentially (one array at the time) as opposed to writing in loop to array[i][0], then array[i+1][0]...

Comment: @AoeAoe Yes of course (and I'm sure David knows what caching means, too), but how does this differ when accessing the array by index or by pointer?

Comment: Some of the functions I got finds 3d points that are within a given range of each other. So I can have cases with hounded of thousands of points where for each point I need to compare it against the rest. Two loops nested.

Comment: @ChristianRau meh, my stupidity. I did read code wrong :/ Sorry, mea culpa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's unlikely to be a significant difference. Possibly the emitted code will be identical. This is assuming a vaguely competent compiler, with optimization enabled. You might like to look at the disassembled code, just to get a feel for some of the things a C optimizer gets up to. You may well conclude, "my code is mangled beyond all recognition, there's no point worrying about this kind of thing at this stage", which is a good instinct.

Conceivably the first code could even be faster, if introducing the `item` pointer were to somehow interfere with any loop unrolling or other optimization that your compiler performs on the first. Or it could be that the optimizer can figure out that `arr[i].foo` is equal to `stack_pointer + sizeof(FooBar) * i`, but fail to figure that out once you use the pointer, and end up using an extra register, spilling something else, with performance implications. But I'm speculating wildly on that point: there is usually little to no difference between accessing an array by pointer or by index, my point is just that any difference there is can come for surprising reasons.

Comment: So accessing a value in an array is the same as accessing a "flat" variable? `foo = bar[4]` has no penalty over `biz = baz`? Would it be different if the array is dynamically allocated?

Comment: @thomthom: I make no promises, but when you access an automatic array by name, the compiler knows where it is on the stack and can optimize accordingly. So `bar[4]` could be calculated at compile time to be at the offset from the stack pointer equal to the offset of `bar`, plus 4 times the size of each element, and there would be no calculation needed at runtime involving the number `4`. Using a pointer to the first element of the array instead of a name, the compiler *might* still be able to figure out what value was assigned to that pointer and do the same optimization, or it might not.

Comment: ... it depends where the pointer came from. Your example is a fairly good candidate for the compiler to notice what's going on, if it does unroll the loop.

Answer (score 2):

If were worried, and felt like micro-optimizing it (or just were in a pointer-oriented mood), I'd skip the integer index and just use pointers all over:

```
struct FooBar arr[10], *item, *end = arr + sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;
for (item = arr; item < end; item++)
  item->foo = 10;
  item->bar = 20;
  item->biz = 30;
  item->baz = 40;
}
```

But please note: I haven't compiled this (or your code) and counted the instructions, which is what you'd need to do. As well as running it and measuring of course, since some combinations of multiple instructions might be faster than shorter sequences of other instructions, and so on.

Comment: And in any case measurement is difficult. If you write a simple benchmark loop, it may or may not reflect real use of the array (how hot the cache is and so on). The optimizer might detect that your benchmark does nothing and apply optimizations that wouldn't be valid in real use. So the only truly sound test of performance is real application code: that is, profile a real app rather than counting instructions or benchmarking small snippets in isolation.

Comment: I understand - there's no obvious advantage. One has to check where the bottleneck is if there is any. That's what I wanted to find out. In Ruby there are so many bottlenecks in regard to looking up values so I'm chronically worried about it and I've learned what patterns are faster than others. The patterns in C appear to be very different. (Not surprisingly.)

Comment: @thomthom Well, it's quite reasonable, considering what range-checking or polymorphism rubbish Ruby might do for a simple array access.